# Why am I receiving this error when I attempt to build Qt from source in Visual Studio 11 Express Beta?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build Qt with Microsoft's 64-bit compiler. I downloaded `qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.0.tar.gz` from [the Qt downloads page](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) and extracted it to `D:\Qt`. After launching the x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt, I ran the following commands:

```
set QTDIR=D:\Qt
set PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin

configure.exe -debug-and-release -opensource -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libmng
 -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-style-windowsvista
 -platform win32-msvc2010
```

The process went quite smoothly for a few minutes, but abruptly stopped with the following error:

```
...
qurl.cpp
qsettings_win.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BI
N\x86_amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
Building qmake failed, return code 2
```

I have *no clue* what is causing that error or what to do about it - the error message is far less than helpful. Here is what my system looks like:

- Windows 8 Consumer Preview 32-bit
- Visual Studio 11.0.50.214.1 Beta Express for Windows 8

---

**Edit:** if I `cd` into the `qmake` directory and run `nmake`, we discover the actual error:

```
qfilesystemengine_win.cpp
qfsfileengine_win.cpp
D:\Qt\src\corelib\io\qfsfileengine_win.cpp(64) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open
include file: 'shlobj.h': No such file or directory
D:\Qt\src\corelib\io\qfilesystemengine_win.cpp(66) : fatal error C1083: Cannot o
pen include file: 'shlobj.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BI
N\x86_amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Why is `shlobj.h` missing?

Comment: `<shlobh.h>` should be in Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um.  It is possible that (a) Qt is not passing that include path to the compiler, or (b) The Visual Studio 11 Beta Express for Windows 8 does not include this header.  To find out, see if the file exists on disk.  Note that the Express for Windows 8 only supports creating Metro style applications.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: So... I'll need to fall back to VS Express 2010 to build Qt? (By the way, the file isn't there.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual Studio 11 Beta Express for Windows 8 only supports Metro style applications.  It doesn't include the full SDK.

To build Qt, you'll need one of the other Visual Studio 11 Beta SKUs, which you can download from [the Visual Studio website](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#vs).  The Ultimate SKU certainly includes `<shlobj.h>`, and probably any other missing headers (of course, that doesn't necessarily mean that Qt will build; it may inadvertently rely on quirks in Visual C++ 2010 or the Beta may have bugs that prevent it from building; your mileage may vary).

Comment: I think I'll just install VC++ 2010 Express to avoid any headaches. Thanks for explaining everything.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I had this issue and the answer wasn't too helpful any more.

This missing file can be found in the windows SDKs. If they are missing you must be missing an SDK. For VS 2010 install the Windows 7.1 SDK and respectively for VS 2012 you will need the windows 8 SDK. 
Default file locations after install:

- Windows 8 SDK:
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um
- WIndows 7 SDK:
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Include
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include

Answer (score 0):

The error code 0x2 maps to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.  Best guess is that one of the arguments of cl.exe is missing.  Based on the output I would say that qsettings_win.cpp is not in the current path, or not present on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when trying to build **Qt 5.3 Beta** for [**WinRT**](http://qt-project.org/wiki/WinRTBuild).

I was on **Windows 8.1** with **VS 2013** (Professional) installed. To fix the problem I had to:

- Download and install [Windows 8.1 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx). It will be placed at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1`;
- Use **VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt**, available at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`.